# C# Get Resource with Variable-Name

Tags: c#, variables, resources

I have a problem regarding my C# Program:

```
        string sound = MyProgram.Properties.Settings.Default.sound;

        if (sound == "Bing")
        {
            Stream str = Resources.bing;
            SoundPlayer soundplayer = new SoundPlayer(Resources.bing);
            soundplayer.Play();
        } else if (sound == "Bong")
        {
            Stream str = Resources.bong;
            SoundPlayer soundplayer = new SoundPlayer(Resources.bong);
            soundplayer.Play();
        }
```

So the code problem is, that this is hardcoded - i want to generate a **dynamical** sound...

Is it possible to do it with an **variable**?

Also: is it possible to play the soundplayer instantly without calling `soundplayer.Play();` in a new line?

Sincerely,
Timo

(PS: My English is not that good so please pardon my short question :D)

Comment: Do you mean sound synthesis?  There is a question about that [here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8712051/sound-synthesis-with-c-sharp)

Comment: Sorry no - i would like to get a resource via variable from an embedded wav file :/

Comment: What do you mean by *dynamical*? Do you want to load the sound from a file, or from the property of `Resources` matching the string name, or something else?

Comment: matching the string name sounds good, i would like to get the sound like this: SoundPlayer soundplayer = new SoundPlayer(Resources."BING");